# Validate arithmetical formula

Tags: java, regex

I need validate a formula to calculate the grade of discipline:

All identifiers (A1, A2,A3,...) has been based on tests, homeworks, etc. created by teachers. Below an example of a common formula:

```
( (A1+A2+A3) / 3) * (B2+B3)
```

On this case, I'm just need validate the formula structure, like:

- Non closed parenthesis (done);
- Empty parenthesis groups '()' (done);
- Duplicated operators like '(A1++A2)';
- Duplicated distinct operators like '(A1 **-*** A2)';

All identifiers at formula like **A1,A1,** etc has been informed by final user, and doesn't validated.

Sample of valid formula:

```
(((A1+A2+A3)/3)*2) + (((B1+B2+B3)/3)*3)
```

Sample of invalid formula:

```
+ (((A1+A2+A3)/3)*2) + (((B1+B2+B3)/3) / 3++)
```

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for such a task.

Comment: search for `infix notation validation` and try to implement it.

Comment: Take a look @ http://irony.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regular expressions are [regular grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) and you need a context-free grammar to parse this kind of stuff (or validate). otherwise, you only apply heuristics...

Comment: I'll try implement your tip and @SAbbasizadeh 's tip. Thanks .